# Understand why parent properties can be accessed from child class but parent objects cannot

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I'm having a hard time understanding why this isn't working. I can access properties of my parent class but not objects.

I've read other threads that indicate I should call `parent::__construct()` from within the below Session class but that just creates an infinite loop and fails.

Why is `$TestVariable` available in the Session class but the `$Cookie` object is not?

Main Application File:

```
class Application
{
    //Class Objects
    public $Cookie = NULL;
    public $Session = NULL;
    public $TestVariable = "Hello World";

    //Object initialization. Singleton design.
    protected function __construct()
    {
        //Initialize cookie object.
        $this->Cookie = Cookie::getCookie();

        //Initialize session object.
        $this->Session = Session::getSession();
    }

    //Returns the singleton instance of The Curator class. Singleton design.
    public static function Initialize()
    {
        static $instance = NULL;

        if($instance === NULL)
        {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

   //Singleton design.
   private function __clone() {}

   //Singleton design.
   private function __wakeup() {}
}
```

Cookie File:

```
class Cookie
{
    //Object initalization. Singleton design.
    protected function __construct()
    {
        //CODE HERE
    }

    //Singleton design.
    private function __clone() {}

    //Singleton design.
    private function __wakeup() {}

    //Returns the singleton instance of the cookie class. Singleton design.
    public static function getCookie()
    {
        static $cookieInstance = NULL;

        if($cookieInstance === NULL)
        {
            $cookieInstance = new static();
        }

        return $cookieInstance;
    }

    //Removes all cookies.
    public function destroyCookies()
    {
        //CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Session File:

```
class Session extends Application
{
    //Object initialization. Singleton design.
    protected function __construct()
    {
        //This FAILS!
        $this->Cookie->destroyCookies();

        //This WORKS!
        echo $this->TestVariable;
    }

    //Singleton design.
    private function __clone() {}

    //Singleton design.
    private function __wakeup() {}

    //Returns the singleton instance of the session class. Singleton design.
    public static function getSession()
    {
        static $sessionInstance = NULL;

        if($sessionInstance === NULL)
        {
            $sessionInstance = new static();
        }

        return $sessionInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because your Session (while it might extend the Application class) is being instantiated in as a new instance in every instance of Application that you create..... either use extension, or use composition; but don't play pick-a-mix; at the very least, it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the parent constructor from the child class.
And the recursion is because you have this:

- Session constructor calls parent::__construct()
- Application constructor calls Session::getSession()
- Inside the Session::getSession() we have `new Session` statement
- Session constructor is invoked
- Session constructor calls parent::__construct()
- ... and so on

So make it work you need to break the chain and move session initialization out of the Application constructor:

```
class Application
{
    //Class Objects
    public $Cookie = NULL;
    public $Session = NULL;
    public $TestVariable = "Hello World";

    //Object initialization. Singleton design.
    protected function __construct()
    {
        //Initialize cookie object.
        $this->Cookie = Cookie::getCookie();
    }

    protected function init() {
        //Initialize session object.
        $this->Session = Session::getSession();
    }

    //Returns the singleton instance of The Curator class. Singleton design.
    public static function Initialize()
    {
        static $instance = NULL;

        if($instance === NULL)
        {
            $instance = new static();
            // Call init after construction
            $instance->init();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

...
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/quick-test/parent.php).

But indeed, the design looks wrong and probably `Session` should not inherit the `Application` at all.